# Cant write http request headers to file in perl

Tags: perl, http, apache2, cgi

I am trying to write http headers from a request to a file. 
The perl script executed alone runs fine and writes to file. But when i invoked the script from a http request, i am getting http 500 error and error log says..'cannot open file' 
I commented that 'open file' line in script and it works perfectly fine when invoked from browser. Please suggest me what wrong i am doing here? 
Below is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use CGI qw(:standard); 
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use Carp; 
use LWP::Simple; 
my $query = CGI->new; 
my $file = '/home/suresh/clientrequest.txt'; 
chmod 644, $file; 
sleep(1); 
open my $flh, '+>>', "$file" or die "Cannot open file"; 
$flh->autoflush(); 
# Read the data here 
print $flh my @keywords = $query->keywords; 
print $flh $query->header(-domain=>'testdomain'); 
print $flh my @names= $query->param; 
close $flh; 
print header; 
print start_html("Welcome"); 
print $ENV{QUERY_STRING}; 
print end_html;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apache` user haven't write access to the file.

To have a better error message, change this line:

```
open my $flh, '+>>', "$file" or die "Cannot open file";
```

to

```
open my $flh, '+>>', "$file" or die "Cannot open file '$file': $!";
```

Comment: Thanks M42, your right, apache user didn't had write permissions, i changed the file permissions to 777 and worked.